# integrity-error django :violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, null, facebook-like, integrity

I build a social media application where all actions are concluded in the same count. However with the like button i get an error even if the code looks exactly the same as the dislike version. The error is:

```
IntegrityError at /like-post
null value in column "num_interactions_total" of relation "core_likepost" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (98, a4aaa95b-a3a5-49a6-8f63-de768bfa0786, 2023-02-02 18:01:13.121023+00, , 1, null, 7).
```

but the num_interactions_total count is already deleted and does not exist in the model or views.py anymore. I've also deleted the migrations. I'm using the postgresql database.

I´m a little confused, why it gives me an error only with this button and not with all the others... How do I avoid the null error?

Here are the models and views from like and dislike:

```
def like_pdf(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = 'post{}.{}'.format(instance.interactions_total, ext)
    return os.path.join('uploads', filename)


class LikePost(models.Model):
    post_id = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    num_likes_total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    interactions_total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pdf_like = models.FileField(upload_to=like_pdf, default=None, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_id


def dislike_pdf(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = 'post{}.{}'.format(instance.interactions_total, ext)
    return os.path.join('uploads', filename)

class DislikePost(models.Model):
    post_id = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    num_dislikes_total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    interactions_total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pdf_dislike = models.FileField(upload_to=dislike_pdf, default=None, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_id




def like_post(request):
    post_id = request.GET.get('post_id')
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    post.number_of_likes = post.number_of_likes + 1
    num_likes_total = LikePost.objects.count() + 1
    interactions_total = InteractionPost.objects.count()
    new_like = LikePost.objects.create(post_id=post_id, num_likes_total=num_likes_total, interactions_total=interactions_total)
    new_like.save()
    new_interaction = InteractionPost.objects.create(post_id=post_id)
    new_interaction.save()
    post.interaction_count = post.interaction_count + 1



    likes_string = ""
    word = "like "

    i = 0
    while i < 1:
        post.likes_string = post.likes_string + word + os.linesep
        i += 1

    post.save()

    # create pdf dislike
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    countobject = UserCount.objects.first()


    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer, pagesize=A4)

    x_start = 50
    y_start = 200
    x = 100
    y = 275

    p.roundRect(x_start, y_start, 500, 400, 10, stroke=1, fill=0)
    p.roundRect(x, y, 400, 300, 10, stroke=1, fill=0)

    p.drawString(100, 700, "new_interaction: like_post // user no.:")
    p.drawString(100, 675, str(new_like.created_at))
    p.drawString(200, 650, str(post.num_post))
    p.drawString(100, 650, "post no.:")
    p.drawString(400, 700, str(countobject))

    p1 = Paragraph(post.dislikes_string)
    p1.wrapOn(p, 400, 1000)
    p1.drawOn(p, 200, 700)

    p2 = Paragraph(post.likes_string)
    p2.wrapOn(p, 400, 1000)
    p2.drawOn(p, 0, 800)
    p.save()

    buffer.seek(0)

    new_like.pdf_like.save(f"post{interactions_total}.pdf", buffer)
    new_like.save()

    return redirect('/')


def dislike_post(request):
    post_id = request.GET.get('post_id')
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    post.number_of_dislikes = post.number_of_dislikes + 1
    num_dislikes_total = DislikePost.objects.count() + 1
    interactions_total = InteractionPost.objects.count()

    new_dislike = DislikePost.objects.create(post_id=post_id, num_dislikes_total=num_dislikes_total, interactions_total=interactions_total)
    new_dislike.save()
    new_interaction = InteractionPost.objects.create(post_id=post_id)
    new_interaction.save()
    post.interaction_count = post.interaction_count + 1

    dislikes_string = ""
    word = "dislike "
    i = 0
    while i < 1:
        post.dislikes_string = post.dislikes_string + word + os.linesep
        i += 1

    post.save()

    #create pdf dislike
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    countobject = UserCount.objects.first()

    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer, pagesize=A4, )

    x_start = 50
    y_start = 200
    x = 100
    y = 275

    p.roundRect(x_start, y_start, 500, 400, 10, stroke=1, fill=0)
    p.roundRect(x, y, 400, 300, 10, stroke=1, fill=0)

    p.drawString(100, 700, "new_interaction: dislike_post // user no.:")
    p.drawString(100, 675, str(new_dislike.created_at))
    p.drawString(200, 650, str(post.num_post))
    p.drawString(100, 650, "post no.:")
    p.drawString(400, 700, str(countobject))

    p1 = Paragraph(post.dislikes_string)
    p1.wrapOn(p, 400, 1000)
    p1.drawOn(p, 0, 300)

    p2 = Paragraph(post.likes_string)
    p2.wrapOn(p, 400, 1000)
    p2.drawOn(p, 110, 600)
    p.save()
    buffer.seek(0)

    new_dislike.pdf_dislike.save(f"post{interactions_total}.pdf", buffer)
    new_dislike.save()

    return redirect('/')
```

I know the code is quite messy.But where does the error come from?

Comment: you checked in real database postgres? You deleted `column num_interactions_total` in database or not? I think problem is you deleted in models.py, migration but forgot delete in postgres db

Comment: @NgocPham yes, I think so too... But how do I access the database to delete and recreate this specific migration? I'm using RDS and I'm a little confused on how to show all my model migrations of the database in the pycharm console. or is it possible to just reset the database? I'm very afraid of messing it all up.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you deleted in models.py, migration but forgot delete in database.

You can manually delete it in db, or do it with commands console

Assum you have 2 migrations in app test_app:

1. 0001_test_1.py
2. 0002_test_2.py  *#have column `num_interactions_total`*

Now want delete `num_interactions_total`. You can revert migrations like:

```
python manage.py migrate test_app 0001_test_1
```

It will back your database to migration `0001_test_1`, revert all changed in `0002_test_2` - delete column `num_interactions_total`